# How to delete multiple entry from list-view by checking check-box in android

Tags: android, android-listview, delete-row, android-checkbox

I have a list-view with check-box which load's data from external database. When i check any particular check-box and press delete then it is deleting that particular value. But my problem is when i check more then one check-box and press delete then it is deleting only last checked value not all the value which is checked.

So what i am doing wrong in my code. can anyone suggest please. Below is my code. Thank you in advance.

**CustomClassAdapter**

```
public class Custom_ClassAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

List<List_ClassModel> rowItems;

public Custom_ClassAdapter(Context context, List<List_ClassModel> rowItems) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTextView;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_class, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.classImage);
        holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.classname);
        holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(position);

    holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
    holder.mCheckBox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Code.classDel = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                }
            });

    List_ClassModel rowItem = (List_ClassModel) getItem(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(rowItem.getClassName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

public void clear() {
}
}
```

**DeleteProduct**

```
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Class... Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            List_ClassModel mlList_ClassModel = Code.arrayClasses
                    .get(Code.classDel);
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", ""
                    + mlList_ClassModel.getClass_ID()));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_delete_class,
                    "POST", params);
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());
            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Code.arrayClasses.remove(Code.classDel);
        mCustom_ClassAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
public static int pm = 0;
public static int dropboxlogout = 0;
public static int currentDel;
public static int classDel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the structure of your code, I think it can be used to delete only a single item.

This is what is happening : When you check item x, this item is stored for deletion. Then, when you check item y, the previous id is overwritten with that of the new one. So, when you are making request to the server, you have only the last checked item with you.

What you can do : Create an ArrayList. Whenever any item is checked, add the item to the ArrayList. Thus you can store as many items as you want for deletion. Finally, while making request to the server, traverse the ArrayList to get the ids of the all the items and send them to the server in your required format.

Answer (score 0):

In the listener below, you store the item you'd like to delete in a public static variable defined in Code class. Any time you check or uncheck (yes, uncheck, because you don't check isChecked variable) classDel variable is overwritten. Therefore, you only delete the last item you interacted.

```
holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Code.classDel = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    }
});
```

What you want to do is create an array list and modify it accordingly. Here's a sample code to do that:

```
holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){ // checked an item, add it to the list
           Code.arrayList.add(buttonView.getTag());
        } else { // unchecked an item, remove it from the list
           Code.arrayList.remove(buttonView.getTag())
        }
    }
});
```

And in your async task traverse through this list and delete all of the items.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    for(int item : Code.arrayList)
       Code.arrayClasses.remove(item);
    mCustom_ClassAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: If i use this above code then what i have to pass here List_ClassModel mlList_ClassModel = Code.arrayClasses.get(Code.classDel); because if i pass Code.arrayList then it is showing error.

Comment: I don't know what you have or do in Code class. You have to update that class accordingly.

Comment: I have just declared classDel as int variable in Code class. public static int classDel;

Comment: you need to make it an arraylist

Comment: But if i do so then i am getting error in this statement. List_ClassModel mlList_ClassModel = Code.arrayClasses
                    .get(Code.arrayList);

Comment: Then modify that method and any other method that is related, too.

Comment: If you share Code class, I can help you.

Comment: It's not the whole class, it's just a bunch of variables.